# Не загружается Manjaro XFCE

Tags: linux, grub, bios, manjaro

Установил Manjaro XFCE на ноутбук и при попытке загрузится появляется чёрный экран без ничего. Тоже самое начало происходить на флешке с ней же. Если включить Secure boot то при загрузке выдаёт это: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhLLx.jpg

Вот настройки boot'а: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiGdl.jpg

Comment: Не понимаю ссылки. Обновите вопрос, добавив необходимую информацию текстом.